# App is running very slow when APN protocol selected as IPV4/IPV6

Tags: android, dns, ipv6, ipv4

I am getting multiple reviews that my app is running very slow on a network that is providing IPV6 type ip. After debugging I got to know that app is unable to resolve host on IPV6 and then try with IPV4 and this transition took around 30 seconds.
Now if I change the APN setting to IPV4 only app works fine.
So my question is What should I do to make my app run on IPV4/IPV6 or is  there any DNS caching that is required if yes Please share some snippet.
Please help this is really getting bigger everyday

Answer (score 1):

One quick fix could be to use a CND like [CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200432324-IPv4-IPv6-Gateway) mainly because you could set up everything in IPv4 and later then just put the CND in front.

The CDN will be an ipv4/ipv6 gateway to your app so you don't have to worry about that switching, you should just provide a domain and that should do the job, something like:

```
app.your-domain.tld.
```

Later for testing, you could use http://cloudflare.ipv6-test.com/validate.php

This setup will help to avoid delays if your app needs to get/fetch content from your servers that are either IPv4/IPv6 no matter what  APN that is been used.

Comment: Thanks but we already have Akamai for this and Ipv6 is enabled. Any other solution guys?

Comment: Akamai works quite well, maybe you could just check your endpoints probably some are not going through the CDN